# Difference between ReservableCurrency and NamedReservableCurrency?

Tags: balances, frame, runtime, tcurrency

The docs on the traits `ReservableCurrency` and `NamedReservableCurrency` currency are the same, although they clearly have subtle differences between them. When should someone use `ReservableCurrency` vs `NamedReservableCurrency`, and how do they differ?

https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.ReservableCurrency.html

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.NamedReservableCurrency.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context for `NamedReserveableCurrency` can be found here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7223
- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/7778

Basically, this was a feature added later in the balances pallet where users could have a reserved balance which is indexed under a certain "name". (usually the pallet which is reserving the balance)

This allows that you are able to see how much balance each pallet has individually reserved, rather than having a single reserved balance which mixes all the balances together.

This can also help prevent an error in one pallet from causing issues in another pallet, for example incorrectly accounting for the reserved balance of a user, and thus taking from a shared pot of reserved balances.